# Is there any way to delete contact from contact list?

Tags: android, adb

My application requires an alternate contact while installing an app.When I run install & register app there are no contacts in new devices bydefault.

I have found an adb command to add an contact in contact list

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Alternate Contact' -e phone 72xxxxxxxx`

But now i am unable to delete same contact after execution .
Tried multiple combination of parameters with next command, but it is not working.
`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Donald Duck' -e phone 72xxxxxxxx`

Please share if there is an adb command to delete contact.

EDIT : `adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.contacts` command will clear all contacts from contact list.

Comment: you should add your edit as an answer to this question

Comment: @RavindraThorat thanks for the suggestion. I have added comment & accepted my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.contacts` command will clear all contacts from a contact list.

Comment: Is there a similar way to delete a particular contact?

Answer (score 6):

To add contact (where're name = 'Mozart', number = '+380505005050')

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name Mozart -e phone +380505005050
```

To edit contact (where's id = 1)

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.EDIT content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1
```

To remove contact (where's id = 1)

```
$ adb shell content delete --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1
```

To remove all contacts at once

```
$ adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.contacts
```

To view specific contact (where's id = 1)

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1
```

To list all contacts

```
$ adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts
```